# on_double_click on table in python/beeware

Tags: python, beeware

I want to access data from a row of my table and display it in the terminal when that row is double-clicked.

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW

class HelloWorld(toga.App):

    def startup(self):
        # Create a table with sample data
        data = [
            ['John', 'Doe', 30],
            ['Jane', 'Smith', 25],
            ['Alice', 'Johnson', 35]
        ]
        table = toga.Table(headings=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'], data=data, on_double_click=self.clicked)

        # Create a main box and add the table to it
        main_box = toga.Box(children=[table], style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    def clicked(self, table, row):
        print("Clicked row", row, "of table", table)


def main():
    app = HelloWorld()
    app.main_loop()
```

I have this output in the terminal, I need the line data and not just object numbers.

Clicked row <toga.sources.list_source.Row object at 0x000001E04101C750> of table Table:0x1e04100a850

Comment: if you have a class, then you need to make an instance of the class...

Comment: @D.L -- That's exactly what `return HelloWord()` does.  I assume you must be calling `main()` somewhere, otherwise this script would do nothing at all.

Comment: You need to use an `on_double_click` handler.  I don't see an attempt to do that here.  https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/widgets/table.html

Comment: @TimRoberts.  it would just return an instance for which nothing happens. what would it do exactly ? no method or attribute is used as far as i can tell...

Comment: That's an issue with big frameworks like `toga` and `Flask` -- you can't tell what's being done for you in the background.  In this specific case, it looks like you're right -- they should be calling `app.main_loop()` at some point.

Comment: I reformulated the question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, and I'm not willing to install `toga` to do so, but here is the kind of thing you need.  Note the changes in `main` and the addition of the `clicked` method.  Please check the documentation to learn how to use the parameters to the callback.

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW


class HelloWorld(toga.App):

    def startup(self):
        # Create a table with sample data
        data = [
            ['John', 'Doe', 30],
            ['Jane', 'Smith', 25],
            ['Alice', 'Johnson', 35]
        ]
        table = toga.Table(headings=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'], data=data, on_double_click=self.clicked)

        # Create a main box and add the table to it
        main_box = toga.Box(children=[table], style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    def clicked(self, table, row):
        print( "Clicked row", row, "of table" table )


def main():
    app = HelloWorld()
    app.main_loop()
```

Comment: Clicked row <toga.sources.list_source.Row object at 0x000001E04101C750> of table <Table:0x1e04100a850>

I've already read all the documents, and my problem is dealing with this output, it's giving me memory objects that I don't know how to extract their data.

Comment: Those are not memory objects.  That's a Toga Table object and a Toga Row object.  `row.age` should give you the age value for the row that was clicked.  `row.last_name` should give you the last name.